# NameError: name 'word' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror, defined

I'm trying to make a mixWord function and I'm getting an error saying
`NameError: name 'word' is not defined`
What am I missing from here?

Here is my function definition:

```
def mixWord(word):
    characterList = list(word);
    print characterList
    import random;
    random.shuffle(characterList);
    print characterList;
    shuffledWord = ''.join(characterList);
    print shuffledWord;
```

and here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<pyshell#79>", line 1, in <module>

mixWord (word)

NameError: name 'word' is not defined
```

Comment: Post the full traceback and the rest of your code. Your error isn't here.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#79>", line 1, in <module>
    mixWord (word)
NameError: name 'word' is not defined

Comment: @user2507566: Please update your question.

Comment: Has the code been [re-]saved to the correct file? Can the error be reproduced when running/editing the code through IDLE? That error should *not* be generated in that position: I suspect that the *actual* code is different than what is believed. (Also, ditch the semicolons - they look bad!)

Comment: Yeah, the code looks fine and works for me.

Comment: I have saved it several times trying different things to get it to work. I've been using IDLE.

Comment: @user2507566 So running the pasted code *directly* from an IDLE buffer ("window") results in that error? I'm not so sure it will ..

Comment: @user2507566: Do you have a `word` variable defined before calling `mixWord(word)`?

Comment: @AnkurAnkan The first line is a function declaration, not an invocation. `word` is not evaluated there.

Comment: im continuing to get an error for some reason. it doesnt define "word"

Comment: @user2246674: I just checked. I am getting the same error if I call `mixWord` without having any `word` declared.

Comment: what did you do to correct it before @user2246674?

Comment: @user2246674: The question hasn't been posted clearly. It's not mentioned that he is getting error while calling the function. But the trace shows that he is calling the function.

Comment: @AnkurAnkan Then the only logical conclusion is the posted code and running code are different.

Comment: I have found what I was messing up, thank you yall for help

Comment: @user2246674: Yes. I even tried editing the question but the edit is getting rejected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are calling `mixWord(word)` without defining any `word` variable.

Comment: how would i define the word variable? sorry im very new to python

Comment: With define I meant that are you having a variable named `word` before calling `mixWord(word)`?

Comment: Before calling `mixWord(word)` simply try `print(word)`. If `print(word)` also gives a `NameError` that means there is no variable by the name 'word'.

Comment: Simply type `word = 'someword'` in python shell and then write your function or you can define the word in your function itself

Comment: Ok I understand now, I see I was just wasnt using my brain at all. Thanks for putting up with me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is PEBKAC - exactly *what* form, is for you to find out.

That is, ***the code executed is not the same as the code posted*; the [posted code works as expected](http://ideone.com/Km3xVN)**:

```
def mixWord(word):
    characterList = list(word);
    print characterList
    import random;
    random.shuffle(characterList);
    print characterList;
    shuffledWord = ''.join(characterList);
    print shuffledWord;

mixWord("PEBKAC")
```

So, find out why:

- Has the file been saved?
- Has the file been saved to the correct location?
- Is the file from the correct location being run?
- Is the error from *different code* entirely?

Also *try running the code directly from an IDLE buffer* as that should be immune to the previous potential issue(s).

After resolving the issue, consider updating the code to *not* using semicolons as they are not required here and it is un-Pythonic.